# Bash no such file or directory

Tags: bash

I'm connecting to another pc via ssh terminal, and I'm able to, but there appeares two lines which are driving me crazy

```
Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted applicable law.
Last login: Thu May 23 12:45:03 2019 from 192.168.45.45
bash: /home/user/newUser: No such file or directory
bash: /home/user/newUser: No such file or directory
```

newUser it's a Script which doesn't belongs on there, so I'm wondering how could I remove these lines

```
$ grep newUser ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2>/dev/null
/home/user/.profile:bash /home/olduser/newUser
/home/user/.profile:bash /home/olduser/newUser
```

Comment: Does `grep newUser ~/.bashrc` return anything?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't return anything

Comment: Or in any other of your dotfiles?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the results of this command when run _on the remote server_, after you log in via ssh: `grep newUser ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2>/dev/null`. That will tell us which of the startup files is the problem.

Answer (score 5):

The offending file is `~/.profile` on the remote system. Just open that file in your favorite text editor:

```
nano ~/.profile
```

Find these lines (looks like the line is repeated 2 times):

```
bash /home/olduser/newUser
```

And delete them. That should solve the problem.